# Magento 1.9 configurable swatches not showing on layered navigation

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd-theme, color-swatches

I am trying out the new configurable swatched in magento 1.9. 
Works fine on the product detail page and the product listing page but the images don't show in the category layered navigation, anybody knows how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Have you set `Product Attribute to Use for Swatches in Product Listing` to `Color` in `System > Configuration > Catalog > Configurable Swatches > General Settings`?

Answer (score 3):

In order to display swatches in layered navigation, you have to use global swatch images  (/media/wysiwyg/swatches) with the same name as the Color attribute label.  Use all lowercase letters and replace non-alphanumeric characters with hyphens. I'm not sure if they must be png. If you have already done this, see Adding Global Swatch Images in the guide for more information: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee1141-ce191-configurable-swatches.

Comment: Thanks. I'll add that the basic swatch colors are in the **Sample Data** for **Magento 1.9**

Answer (score 0):

There are a few steps to get Magento 1.9x default RWD Color Swatches to show in the layered navigation.

1. Go to your attribute and make sure it is set to global
   [image: screenshot of color attribute]
2. Ensure that you know the exact name of your color that is listed in the Admin column and save your images with this file name
   [image]
3. Save your image as a PNG file. If your Admin Label in step 2 contains any spaces or special characters, be sure to replace those with hyphens and replace uppercase with lowercase in the filename. (ie: Black Powdercoat should be black-powdercoat.png)
4. Now head over to edit any CMS Page or Static Block and Insert an image
5. Be sure to click on the root folder, then click create folder, and create a folder named "swatches" (all lowercase).
6. Upload your images...
7. And there you have it...

I will post pictures of the full process once I have more "reputation points".