# Color swatches as filters in layered navigation in Magento 1.9.3.7

Tags: magento1.9.3

I am reading the documentation for Magento's configurable swatches and I cant figure out if I can use that feature for the following scenario:

1. I have several different Simple Products at different colors.
2. I have a color attribute
3. I am setting the relevant color in each product.

Right now, in layered navigation I get the text for each color. I have tried to use Configurable swatches for this attribute, but when I activate the option I still see the header Color in layered navigation, but is empty. I dont see neither the color images I have uploaded in media/wysiwyg/swatches, or the text.

So, is there a way I can use images instead of text in layered navigation for this scenario?

Comment: I'd look here - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/49194/magento-1-9-configurable-swatches-not-showing-on-layered-navigation

Comment: The link you've provided is regarding configurable products. I am looking to see if i can use just for layered navigation filtering  for simple products

Comment: Do you already have images for your color attribute, and are you loading them into the product with that attribute name? You'll want to read the answers on that link to see how you can get images associated to your attributes and then have them display in layered navigation

Comment: Yes, I have already have the images for the color attribute in the proper place and I have set the color for each attribute.

Comment: Do you mind sharing the URL? You can edit the comment to remove later

Comment: Its on a production localhost

Comment: Which theme are you using? Have you tried using RWD and testing if the images show in the layered navigation then? Might be a limitation of how your custom theme was setup.

Comment: I have tried with both the default theme and with RWD theme. No images are shown. So I am just wondering if the above scenario is doable at all, or if it requires configurable products...